# Android: SlidingLayer Event Listener Onclose

Tags: java, android

I use [slidinglayer](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib) from 6wunderkinder. Now I want to do something if the slide closed. Therefore I want that a function is called. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to implement `OnInteractListener`. It fires 4 callback

1. onOpen
2. onClose
3. onOpened
4. onClosed

   ```
   yourSlidingMenuInstance.setOnInteractListener(new OnInteractListener() {
      @Override
      public void onOpen() {}

      @Override
      public void onClose() {}

      @Override
      public void onOpened() {}

      @Override
      public void onClosed() {}
   });
   ```